# Custom loop in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I would like to use Matter.js with my custom game loop, I followed instructions from [here](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Rendering) and added Engine.update(engine, 1000/60, 1); in draw loop, but nothing happens, just blank screen. Do I need to add tick method somewhere?

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {

    // Matter.js module aliases
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        World = Matter.World,
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

    // create a Matter.js engine
    var engine = Engine.create(document.body);

    // create two boxes and a ground
    var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
    var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
    var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

    // add all of the bodies to the world
    World.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

    // run the engine
    //Engine.run(engine);

    draw();

    function draw(){ 
        Engine.update(engine, 1000/60, 1);        

        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: What did you expect to happen based on this code? You've initialized some matter.js objects without a renderer, then started a custom loop that doesn't render anything. The MJS engine is running a simulation you can't see. Try adding some rendering code to reflect what MJS is doing to the bodies by drawing them on canvas, DOM, p5.js, etc. See [Using Matter.js to render to the DOM or React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906218/using-matter-js-to-render-to-the-dom-or-react/65354225#65354225) for DOM examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong parameters.
I have a function working with `Engine.update` that looks like this:

```
var updateTime = 1000/60;
Matter.Engine.update(engine, [delta=updateTime], [correction=1]);
```