# How do I determine the origin of the physics engine

Tags: reactjs, matter.js

I was using `matte.js`, using my own rendering, and it was fine until I suddenly found out how `matter` knew the origin of my canvas, that is, when I created the rigid body, how did its position x,y determine where it was, and I didn't know how `matter` did it, I didn't make any additional Settings

```js
import Matter from "matter-js";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Discuss = () => {
  const Engine = Matter.Engine;
  const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
  const Composite = Matter.Composite;

  const viewWidth = window.innerWidth - 5
  const viewHeight = window.innerHeight - 80

  const discussRef = useRef(null);
  // create engine
  const engine = Engine.create();

  useEffect(() => {
    const ground = Bodies.rectangle(viewWidth / 2, viewHeight, viewWidth, 30, { 
      isStatic: true }
    );
    const ceiling = Bodies.rectangle(viewWidth / 2, -100, viewWidth, 200, { 
      isStatic: true }
    );
    const leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(-100, viewHeight / 2, 200, viewHeight, {
        isStatic: true,
      }
    )
    const rightWall = Bodies.rectangle(viewWidth + 100, viewHeight / 2, 200, viewHeight, {
      isStatic: true,
    }
  )
    const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine,{
      element: discussRef.current,
      constraint: {
        stiffness: 0.2,
      }
    });

    Composite.add(engine.world, [ceiling, ground, leftWall, rightWall, mouseConstraint]);

    (function rerender() {
      render(bubbles) //Ignoring him, I did a lot of other things
      Matter.Engine.update(engine);
      requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
    })();
    })

  return (
    <main className="min-h-[calc(100vh-80px)] relative">
      <div ref={discussRef} className="w-full h-[calc(100vh-80px)] relative"></div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

My code ran without any problems, I was just wondering why the engine's origin (0, 0) happened to be on my `discussRef.current`, how did I do this, I started to assume it was there, and suddenly I didn't make any Settings.

Here's the render related code:

```js
const bubbles = messages.map((messageObject, index) => {
  const {text, body} = createBubbleMessage(discussRef.current, 
      messageObject.message)
  Composite.add(engine.world, body)
  return {text, body}
   })

  const render = (bubbles) => {
    bubbles.forEach((bubble, index) => {
    const element = bubble.text
    const body = bubble.body
    const {x, y} = body.position
    element.style.left = `${x - element.offsetWidth/2}px`
    element.style.top = `${y - element.offsetHeight/2}px`
    element.style.transform = `rotate(${body.angle}rad)` 
  })
```

`createBubbleMessage` returns an element(as text) and a rigid body with no internal problems

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Please show `render()`, since that's what draws the bodies, presumably using positions from MJS. BTW, this code leaks memory--you'll want to destroy all your matter state and animation frame in the `useEffect` callback as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354225/6243352). If you're using a similar setup, then MJS doesn't know anything about the canvas--the canvas asks MJS for the body positions and draws accordingly. MJS is the source of truth for positions, the canvas just mirrors what's going on in the MJS physics engine.

Comment: Thanks to the big guy, I just want to ask, I don't Render like the official `Matter. render`, which can be specified on a canvas, and the size of the physical world can be set, but I don't do that in these codes, how does he know the position of my physical world in the canvas? So how is it that the origin of the physical world is in the upper left corner of my canvas, without me specifying it, thank you very much for your answer, I have edited the question

Comment: On top of that I see a memory leak problem, but I still want to know the answer to my original question,thanks

Comment: I tried to explain that--hopefully my explanation made sense. But beyond that, both have an origin at the top left, which is common for almost all canvas-related libraries.

Comment: Let me say another scenario, if I now have a 500 x 500 canvas in the center of the web page, okay, now I need to render the physical world onto this canvas, how do I make sure that the physical world is on this canvas that I specified, and let the top left corner of the canvas be the (0,0) of the physical world, do something to do that, This should be a good explanation of what I want to ask, thank you for your patient explanation

Comment: @ggorlen ， I've modified your previous example to try to show you what I'm talking about, and you can look at this link: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ye-qin/pen/ZEwjOvB), The box is not in the top left corner of the html, it's in the top left corner of the container, and I want to ask why is that, I didn't do anything to set it up, it just naturally positioned there

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it--maybe I'm not understanding the problem. Both matter.js and HTML5 canvas use 0, 0 as the top-left corner. That's just how it's designed.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for some time, I have some guesses.
First of all, I understand a point of view, physics engine is based on Newtonian mechanics to describe the physical characteristics of the object itself and the effect on other objects, using variables such as mass, speed, friction, air resistance to describe specifically, using a physical world to carry these objects with physical characteristics, and then render them together into visible container elements.
Usually, the physical world and the container elements overlap, but one is invisible and the other is visible to us. Absolute positioning is used to determine the location of the object in the physical world. The reference is the physical world. Through real-time binding of the position relationship between the two, through the calculation inside matter.js, dom element is relative to the container element, that is, the object is relative to the physical world, so that the container element and the physical world are coincident, forming a deeply binding relationship.
The question of all this comes from the use of

```js
Matter.Render.create({
element: // A dom element or canvas
})
```

[image]

however, when rendering without Matter.Render, we don't manually determine a container element, which matter.js does for us.
Unfortunately, I didn't find the source code, so I'll just say that this is my guess.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it quite a bit. Physics engines don't need a container to work, they just use math to manipulate objects that (basically) have a bunch of float properties. They're totally headless. Each tick, you ask MJS for the body positions and render them on the container manually in a way that meets your needs. Because MJS was designed with the web environment in mind, the origin (0, 0) is the top left of the MJS view of the world as well as canvas and DOM elements. If that wasn't the case, you could still translate MJS position values into whatever coordinate format you want.

Comment: MJS just happened to include a prototyping renderer front-end that happens to use canvas. This confuses developers to no end, because they assume this is _the only/main way_ to use MJS, when it's really just a sideline feature that doesn't need to exist. The renderer is totally nonessential to the physics engine, which works in numbers only and has no concept of rendering. The physics engine's input is its API and its output is basically a bunch of body positions, all basically text/numbers, no graphics.

Comment: You're right. I never understood it before